# Relations handling with explicit many to many relation

Tags: prisma, planetscale

I’m using PlanetScale to host my database and Fastify with Prisma to build a simple API.

I read the documentation about the things to consider, most notably the missing support of foreign keys.

I followed the guide to [create indexes on foreign keys](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/planetscale#how-to-create-indexes-on-foreign-keys) and also the guide to [create explicit many-to-many relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations) but then I can’t use anymore all the cool features of Prisma.

I currently have the following schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DB_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model Owner {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String   @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  pets      Pet[]
  createdBy String   @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Pet {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String   @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  owners    Owner[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

After the explicit many-to-many relation is introduced, here is the schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DB_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model Owner {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String         @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  pets         OwnersOfPets[]
  createdBy    String         @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt    DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime       @updatedAt
}

model Pet {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String         @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  owners       OwnersOfPets[]
  createdAt    DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime       @updatedAt
}

model OwnersOfPets {
  pet     Pet   @relation(fields: [petId], references: [id])
  petId   Int
  owner   Owner @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId Int

  @@id([petId, ownerId])
  @@index([petId])
  @@index([ownerId])
}
```

For reference, here is the generated `OwnersOfPetsWhereUniqueInput` type:

```js
export type OwnersOfPetsWhereUniqueInput = Prisma.AtLeast<{
  ownerId_petId?: OwnersOfPetsOwnerIdPetIdCompoundUniqueInput
  AND?: OwnersOfPetsWhereInput | OwnersOfPetsWhereInput[]
  OR?: OwnersOfPetsWhereInput[]
  NOT?: OwnersOfPetsWhereInput | OwnersOfPetsWhereInput[]
  ownerId?: IntFilter<"OwnersOfPets"> | number
  petId?: IntFilter<"OwnersOfPets"> | number
  owner?: XOR<OwnerRelationFilter, OwnerWhereInput>
  pet?: XOR<PetRelationFilter, PetWhereInput>
}, "ownerId_petId">
```

The issue is that I have some pretty simple existing code to connect owners to pets which is now broken as I need to transform several things to a new much more complicated syntax:

```js
const pet = await request.server.prisma.pet.findUnique({
  where: { id },
  // Before schema change
  // include: { owners: true },
  // After schema change
  include: { owners: { include: { owner: true } } },
})

// Some more code

await request.server.prisma.pet.update({
  where: { id },
  data: {
    // Some new data
    ...omit(request.body, 'owners'),
    owners: {
      // Before schema change
      // connect: [{ name: 'Henry' }, { name: 'James' }],
      // After schema change
      connect: [
        { petId_ownerId: { petId: id, ownerId: 1 } },
        { petId_ownerId: { petId: id, ownerId: 2 } },
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

As you can see, the code is much more complicated with a very simple use case… Plus, I can’t use the unique `name` field of Owners to connect to the Pet.

Also, the `connectOrCreate` feature is inherently broken with the introduction of the explicit many-to-many relation table, because it requires to provide both a `petId` and `ownerId`, which I obviously don’t have yet in the `create` case.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it expected that I don’t get the same DX as with implicit many-to-many relations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been [answered in a Github discussion](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/21767#discussioncomment-7486763):

> Using an explicit many-to-many relation instead of an implicit one can make the Prisma Client API more complex. However, the advantage of using explicit many-to-many relations is that you can define extra fields on the relation table, which can be useful for storing additional information about the relation.
>
> In your case, you're now connecting `Pet` to `Owner` through the `OwnersOfPets` model, which requires you to specify the `petId` and `ownerId` in the connect clause. This is why you can't use the unique `name` field of `Owner` to connect to the `Pet` anymore, because the connection is now being managed through the `OwnersOfPets` model. While the developer experience (DX) might be different when using explicit many-to-many relations compared to implicit ones, this is the expected behavior and not something you're doing wrong.